# Deceptive site ahead in Chrome using Laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel

I just created a new laravel project, added heavy amount of scss code to it, then used laravel mix to compile scss to css.

Including css file: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">`

Contents of css is absolutely clean, has no malware, redirections, etc. But Chrome keeps complaining about: http://a78c437e.ngrok.io/css/app.css

How can a css file be harmful? It stops complaining only if i comment out that link to `app.css`, if i rename app.css to something different, still not helping.

Laravel 5.6 / Laravel Valet 2.0.12

Here's the results from google safe browsing checker: https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search?url=http:%2F%2Fa78c437e.ngrok.io%2Fcss%2Fapp.css&hl=en-US

Comment: If you are 100% sure then you can contact Google after you verify that you own the domain and that it is secure and this can get the notice removed AFAIK.

Comment: Are you sure that nothing else has changed on your server? You should ensure that there are no other malicious files and check your access logs too.

Comment: @Script47, it's on my local dev machine, other sites are working, just this one. Checked all files with antimalware scanners, etc, everything is clean.

Comment: guys, sleep solved the issue, i dunno how is this related at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated ngrok and it was fixed by itself.

Answer (score -2):

Use the "https" version of ngrok url, it should let you work out

Comment: https doesn't help, same happening.

Comment: How would this fix the issue?